# How to compress so that zip-archive has the same timestamp as source file/source folder

Tags: batch-file, zip, dotnetzip

how do I batch compress some files/folders in individual zip-files so that each individual zip-archive has the correct timestamp (created/modified) as its source file/folder to preserve the chronology of a folder of zip-archives ?

I have downloaded Dotnetzip, using Windows 7..

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Will getting timestamps from `FileInfo` or `DirInfo` on the sources and setting on the archive files be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, that would be sufficient.. I am struggling very much with this as I am using Powershell for the first time.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear that it's programming-related. Possibly add Powershell tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be done with DotnetZip.

An alternative you might always resort to is to *touch* the file after creation. I use `touch` from `unxutils`. And do something like this...

```
7zip a myzip.zip myfile.txt
touch myzip.zip -r myfile.txt
```